# Returning a Task in app.GetMap() function

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task

I'm trying to write a simple string from the user-agent request headers in to the browser.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", (context) => return context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString(););
app.Run();
```

This gives a compile error `Cannot convert expression type 'string' to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'`.

What is the proper solution to this. From what I understand I need to wrap the string `context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();` with a Task but i don't really know how to do this properly inside the arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

`app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) => context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());`

It's because the name of parameter is not important. If you look at the picture, you can see the compiler supposes that the parameter is a `HttpRequest`, not a `HttpContext`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
Task.FromResult(context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());
```

Comment: I don't think this works. I've tried `Task.FromResult("test");` just in case as well and it returns a blank page.

Comment: What about this: `app.MapGet("/", () => "test");`

Comment: Yes this works. However i need the context to get passed on.

Comment: What about this one: `app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext context) => context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString());`? This works for me.

Comment: Amazing this actually works! Thank you. I wish i knew why it doesn't work without explicitly defining the type. Both seem to be recognized as HttpContext inside the arrow function. Please edit your response and i'll mark it as correct answer.